# lit-element property observer event change

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-element

Recommended way to configuring observers on a property value change event.

Currently using the updated method and looping through the changedProperties parameter which works.

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    testprop: { type:String }, 
  };
updated(changedProperties) {
  changedProperties.forEach((oldValue, propName) => {
    if (propName=='testprop') {
      console.log('testprop CHANGED!');
      this.dosomething();
    }
  });
}
```

But seems more overly complicated compared to Polymer 2.0:

```
testprop: {
  type:String,
  value: '',
  observer: 'dosomething',
},
```

To observe a property event change and run some code, is there a simpler / recommended way of doing things?

Comment: Have you tried using property setters?

Comment: great suggestion - property setters work and is much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Alan's suggestion:

```
set testprop(val) {
  let oldVal = this._testprop;
  this._testprop = val;
  this.requestUpdate('testprop', oldVal);
  this.dosomething();
}
get testprop() { return this._testprop; }
```

Comment: A full example here https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties which explain that if have your own `set`, you must have `get` and that's great to use an attribute prefixed by _